# How do I install this 2-pin fluorescent light bulb?

Tags: lighting

I feel so ridiculous posting this but am annoyed and sucking it up.

I have a long and skinny fluorescent light bulb I'm trying to install into a fixture with [pics here](https://imgur.com/a/UeIUbtc).

[image: Tube end]

[image: Socket/tombstone]

YouTube videos say to install it with the bulb metal prongs perpendicular to the floor, and then you kind of "rotate" it in place.  I don't think this is how my install works for some reason.  I can't figure it out and can't seem to get it to click in place.

Do I just have to apply enough pressure and shove the two prongs of the light bulb in between the space of the thin gold filament and center white portion of the fixture?  The 2 prongs I'm certain should be parallel with the floor.   I'm nervous that with the pressure I'm currently applying, it's not right and I'm going to force break something.  When I do lightly touch it this way, the light comes on in the bulb briefly.  There is no "insert and twist" mechanism I can see here that every YouTube video mentions.

I was told elsewhere to try to spin the black part.  I tried manually spinning the black part using my fingernails. It's not budging, either counter clockwise or clockwise. Applied a decent amount of pressure, even trying stuff like pushing down slightly like it's a child proof cap, and still got nothing with it turning. Do I need an appreciable amount of force, or should it be easier? Like would I need pliers to grab a good hold of it?

How do I get this sucker in??

EDIT: I think I may have damaged the fixture somewhat.  There's another bulb that I removed, correctly, by twisting it and taking it out vs. how I took down the original bulb.  The way it aligned made installing a new bulb go in the way it should with an easy insertion and rotation.  So I guess I'll see if somehow to fix the actual fixture itself.

Comment: Imgur not working right now, but if the both ends of the fixture look like a circle with a line/slot in the middle, that is how it works.  Both ends of the tube should go in together and turn, don't try with just one end at a time.  Also turn off the power before you get shock and fall off the ladder.

Comment: There should be a slot to slide the pins through (as seen in the white part) in the black part as well. Something is definitely not normal here, and perhaps just plain wrong. Perhaps it's jammed too far in and needs to be pulled back a bit to rotate so the slots line up? Not a common issue IME. The fact that the left side of the "tombstone" is dislodged from the fixture is not good. Might be new tombstone time.

Comment: The other day I was getting ready to paint around and tidy up flourescent lights in the same dang rental property for the third time. It suddenly dawned on me: Why don't I just install recessed lights in here? All the time was spent on repairing the ceiling under the old light.

Comment: Thanks all.  I added an EDIT to the original post.  I must've damaged the fixture somehow.

Comment: Well it looks like the most common type of tombstone, so a random one bought at a hardware is likely to fit. Change in pairs, or for aesthetics, quads. You have the short tombstones that only work with T8 tubes.

Comment: Do all of your tombstones have that black stuff in them? I have not seen tombstones with thst black stuff in them. Is it removable? It will interfere with insertion and rotation of the tube.

Answer (score 4):

1. The "tombstone" (socket for the bulb) has partly come away from the fixture, in the top left corner.  Depending on how easily the fixture can be disassembled you may be able to put it back.
2. I *think* the black ring inside the bulb socket is a kind of "door".  It's unusual.  But I think it rotates with the blub, and currently it is incorrectly rotated to the "closed" position.

With power off at the breaker, you can

1. rotate that black ring a quarter turn.  Then you ought to be able to insert a bulb, and turn it back (and the ring with it).   Temporarily turn on the power to see if it works.
2. Then turn it off again, disassemble the fixture as much as required to get the little tab on the left side of the tombstone back inside, and put it back together.

If either of those is too difficult, or if step 1 fails, you *could* take the fixture apart and look for replacement parts but my suggestion would be to replace it entirely with an LED fixture.

Comment: Good catch, I missed the bulb retainer had rotated which would prevent bulb insertion. +1

Answer (score 1):

Your question is completely sane under the circumstances.

Yes, you insert the tube with pins vertically oriented, then you rotate 90 degrees to horizontal.

Your particular lampholder ("tombstone") has a rotating plastic guard. It's designed to rotate with the tube, but somehow it has found itself in the theoretically impossible position where it is horizontal while the bulb is removed.

> I was told elsewhere to try to spin the black part. I tried manually spinning the black part using my fingernails.

That's not going to happen, you need a special "key" for that.  It needs to be round, have two pins 1/2” apart sticking out of its ends, the pins are 1/4” long. Insert that key horizontally, turn 90 degrees and Bob's your uncle.

Where do you get such a key?  No idea but  I just have this nagging feeling like ***I've SEEN one*** somewhere. Where have I seen that key???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The plastic piece that you install the bulb into is called a ***Tombstone***.

The pins from the bulb should be lined up vertically, pushed upward into the tombstone and then rotated 90°.

Sometimes this can be difficult and the bulb should not be forced as it can break the bulb.